# PostGIS ST_Split is not working

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st

I want to split/cut polygon into 2 polygons by line.I am using PostGIS ST_Split functionality.Below is code tried so far [with reference](http://postgis.org/documentation/manual-2.1SVN/ST_Split.html),passing two edge point coordinates creating line, by that line spiting polygon

```
select ST_Multi((ST_Split(geom,ST_MakeLine(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(77.708,13.164), 4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(77.71,13.163), 4326))))) as _geom from itpark_plot30
```

But its return same polygon.As show below image there is polygon called "A" and want to split into "B" and "C" but above code returning "A" only.

[image]

my polygon geom is:

```
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
```

**Result**:
with line start and end point are 77.7085,13.1633 and 77.7102,13.1633

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your query:

Have a look at this

[image: my poly]

Then, I get split geometries:

```
select ST_AsText((ST_Dump(ST_Multi((ST_Split(geom,ST_MakeLine(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(104.222,53.33), 4326),ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(104.455,51.15), 4326))))))).geom) as _geom from surf;
```

The result is:

[image: result image]

So, maybe the thing is that your initial poly is not the WGS84 clearly defined?and they are not spatially intersected.
My polygon (`select st_asewkt(geom) from surf`) is

`SRID=4326;POLYGON((103.783338 53.15,105.216672 52.95,105.333338 52.3,105.416671 52.033334,105.161671 51.576667,104.603338 51.451667,103.683338 51.716667,103.266672 52.2,103.200005 52.433334,103.215005 52.628334,103.900005 52.483334,103.863338 52.613334,103.666672 53.15,103.783338 53.15))`

Secondly, is your blade correct? I mean perhaps polygon is not covered by your blade line

Your query is ok. Check your geometries

Comment: SRID is 4326 still not getting two polygons

Comment: I want split polygons to be insert as two separate rows in table

Comment: @veenahosur that's a slightly different requirement than your query suggests, you might want to edit your question to insert that information.

Comment: insertion is ok first i have to get two polygons that is only not working

Comment: I tried with your given example in your case its working.but what is issue in my case not getting

Comment: @veenahosur I am almost sure that your points fall *inside* of the polygon! if you want to be sure, post the WKT of the polygon in your answer for us to check.

Comment: updated my question with geometry in text

Comment: @veenahosur see my updated answer

Comment: @ThingumaBob  great work.Thank you .finally i changed my line start and end point with 77.7085,13.1633 and 77.7102,13.1633 and i got result

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your blade is *precise*, that is, its boundary (the start/end vertices) has to be at least *exactly* on the boundary of the polygon, or outside.

PostGIS stores floating point precision coordinates (up to 15 decimal digits), and its functions are sensitive to that precision up to the last digit; the point coordinates you provide are *way* less precise, and might just be inside the actual polygon by a fraction of a milimeter.

---

`ST_Split` always returns a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, and your `ST_Multi` construct will not work; use `ST_ColectionHomogenize` to extract a *Multi* geometry from a (homogeneous) collection:

```
WITH
 poly AS (
  SELECT 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY AS geom
 ),
 line AS (
  SELECT 'LINESTRING(0 1, 2 1)'::GEOMETRY AS geom
 )
SELECT ST_AsText( ST_CollectionHomogenize( ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom) ) ) AS geom
FROM   poly AS a,
       line AS b
;
                             geom                              
---------------------------------------------------------------
 MULTIPOLYGON(((0 0,0 1,2 1,2 0,0 0)),((0 1,0 2,2 2,2 1,0 1)))
(1 row)
```

---

If you want to have singleton polygons extracted from the `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`, simply dump them:

```
WITH                                                        
 poly AS (
  SELECT 'POLYGON((0 0, 0 2, 2 2, 2 0, 0 0))'::GEOMETRY AS geom
 ),
 line AS (
  SELECT 'LINESTRING(0 1, 2 1)'::GEOMETRY AS geom
 )
SELECT ST_AsText( (ST_Dump( ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom) )).geom ) AS geom
FROM   poly AS a,
       line AS b
;
              geom              
--------------------------------
 POLYGON((0 0,0 1,2 1,2 0,0 0))
 POLYGON((0 1,0 2,2 2,2 1,0 1))
(2 rows)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

These are your geometries:

[image]

To cut that polygon, the line needs to **fully cross** it!

Comment: Great work! I was pretty sure the blade line is incorrect...

Comment: @Jane yeah it just *had* to be...sry for spamming your answer ,)

Comment: An excellent example of the case when the OP is not able to accept the correct answer !!!